Не работает js на модальное окно в bootstrap
При заполнении формы рассчитывания стоимости, кнопка отправить не срабатывает, в свою очередь и не выходит окно уведомления с должным результатом расчетов.



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#orderForm').on('submit', function() {
    let tour = $("#inp1").val();
    let date = new Date($("#inp2").val());
    let month = date.getMonth();
    let kol = $("#inp3").val();
    kol = Number(kol);
    let email = $("#inp4").val();
    let stoim = 0;
    if (tour == 'Крым') {
      if ((month == 5) || (month == 6) || (month == 7) || (month == 8)) {
        stoim = kol * 500;
      } else {
        stoim = kol * 300;
      }
    }
    if (tour == 'Кавказ') {
      if ((month == 12) || (month == 1) || (month == 2) || (month == 5) || (month == 6) || (month == 7) || (month == 8)) {
        stoim = kol * 300;
      } else {
        stoim = kol * 250
      }
    }
    if (tour == 'Алтай') {
      {
        stoim = kol * 1000;
      }
    }
    alert(`Примерная стоимость вашего тура на ${kol} человек составит ${stoim} у.е. Мы свяжемся с ВАМИ!`);
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <img id="logo" src="img/logo.jpg" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <h1>Путешествуйте с нами!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div id="menu">
    <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column flex-sm-row">
      <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link" href="index.html">Главная</a>
      <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link" href="tours.html">Туры</a>
      <a class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link" href="contacts.html">О нас</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="flex">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        Наши туры
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="tour">
            <img src="img/crimea.jpg" class="tour_img" alt="Крым">
            <p>Это прекрасная возможность отдохнуть всей семьей</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">
                                Рассчитать стоимость
                            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="tour">
            <img src="img/kavkaz.jpg" class="tour_img" alt="Кавказ">
            <p>Море, солнце, горы!</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">
                                Рассчитать стоимость
                            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="tour">
            <img src="img/altay.jpg" class="tour_img" alt="Алтай">
            <p>Незабываемые впечатления!</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">
                                Рассчитать стоимость
                            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalScrollableTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle">Рассчитать стоимость</h5>
          <button type="button" class="Close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="max-width: 600px;">
          <form method="get" action="#" id="orderForm">
            <div class="tour">
              <label for="name" class="label">
                                    Выберите тур:
                                </label>
              <select id="inp1">
                <option value="Крым" selected>Крым</option>
                <option value="Кавказ">Кавказ</option>
                <option value="Алтай">Алтай</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="tour">
              <label class="label" for="data">
                                    Выберите дату начала:
                                </label>
              <input type="date" id="inp2">
            </div>
            <div class="tour">
              <label class="label" for="number">
                                    Выберите количество участников:
                                </label>
              <select id="inp3">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2" selected>2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="tour">
              <label class="label" for="email">
                                    Ваш E-Mail:
                                </label>
              <input type="email" id="inp4" class="input-xlarge" style="width: 350px;" required="required">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Отправить</button>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Может есть ошибки в консоли?
